# Dapper Deserializing XML

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, orm, dapper

If I have XML stored in an nvarchar, does Dapper (or Dapper extensions) have a means to deserialize the XML into a DataContract type or a type with XmlRoot / XmlElement annotations?

If it does not handle it directly, is there an idiom for this?  For example, perhaps my target DataContract class has a property that Dapper attempts to set, and that property performs the deserialization of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently it will not attempt to do anything special with this, except assign it to a string property that matches the column name. For now, I would suggest simply: separate the "get the data" and "deserialize the data into objects" steps.  It is perhaps something that could be considered as an additional feature, but it isn't something that exists currently.

Comment: Does Dapper support `xml` data type?

Comment: Have a look in [SqlMapper.cs (line 687)](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper%20NET40/SqlMapper.cs#L687) for your answer, which currently is "no".

Comment: Marc Gravell, What is the situation today (Mar. 2, 2021)? I am getting a null both when I have a string property and when I have an XElement property with the corresponding name. I recommended to the team that the SP be changed to return the XML as string. Is this the best solution?

Answer (score 3):

I think Dapper has already [supports](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L232) `XML` data type as of v1.50.5 (or earlier version), it can convert `XML` data type to `XmlDocument`, `XDocument` or `XElement`.

It did convert `XML` data type to `XElement` in my code.

**Sample Code on 3/5/2021**

A stored procedure that returns data of type XML:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetCarInformation
AS
DECLARE @Cfg XML
SET @Cfg = '<Configuration>
    <A>111</A>
    <B>222</B>
</Configuration>'

SELECT 1 AS Id, 'Test' AS Name, @Cfg AS [Configuration]
```

Code Sample:

```
/* Program.cs */

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Dapper;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* query XML data from database */
            using var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=; Initial Catalog=; User ID=; Password=");
            Car car = connection.Query<Car>("EXEC spGetCarInformation").First();
            Console.WriteLine(car.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(car.Configuration.Element("A").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(car.Configuration.Element("B").Value);

            /* Insert XML data into database */
            car = new Car
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "New Car",
                Configuration = new XElement
                (
                    "Configuration",
                    new XElement("A", "333"),
                    new XElement("B", "444")
                )
            };

            string cmdText = @"CREATE TABLE #Car
(
    Id INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(128),
    Configuration XML
)

INSERT INTO #Car
VALUES
    (@Id, @Name, @Configuration)
    
SELECT * FROM #Car

DROP TABLE #Car";

            Car result = connection.Query<Car>(cmdText, car).First();
            Console.WriteLine(result.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(result.Configuration.Element("A").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(result.Configuration.Element("B").Value);
        }
    }

    class Car
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public XElement Configuration { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Nuget Packages added in project:

```
<PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.78" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="2.1.2" />
```

I tested the code on .NET 5, but should work on .Net Framework 4.7.2+ and System.Data.SqlClient as well.

Comment: Ricky, can you, please provide a simple/small working code example? In my code Dapper is returning null for a field of type XML, when the expected correct result would be an instance of XElement.

Comment: Thank you, Ricky. +1. What about a code sample of the reverse: writing a Car instance into a table in the database, which has a column Car of type XML?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev if you still need this, please see my answer.

Comment: @ChrisPeacock Thanks, I think I was able to solve this problem at the time, but still thanks! Upvoted your answer!

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answer by @Ricky, if you need to write a row containing an XML column to the database, the `Insert` method does not seem to work and leaves the XML column as `NULL`.

The following snippet shows how an `XElement` can be written to a table containing an XML column:

```
var xElement = new XElement(...);

var newRowId = sqlConnection.QuerySingle<int>(@"
    INSERT INTO MyTable (MyXmlField)
    VALUES (@myXml);                    
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    ", new { myXml = xElement });
```